# Cannot see remote Build Agent from server in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

Scenario:

TeamCity Server is installed on server A (running Windows Server 2003). Build Agend was installed both directly in first atempt and through Agent Push in second attempt on development machine B (running Windows 7).

builtAgent.properties is properly configured. On machine B I create a firrewall rule to allow port 9090 for both UDP and TCP. Server seems to reach remote agent, but unsuccesfull (see log snippets):

Log from Server side (machine A):

```
[2014-02-19 14:52:22,698]   WARN -   jetbrains.buildServer.SERVER - Exception occurred while communicating by XML RPC: ClientAbortException:  java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host /remote: 192.168.70.229:50166
```

Log from Agent side (machine B):

```
[2014-02-19 10:37:20,199]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registering on server http://buserver.ff.local, AgentDetails{Name='DREPTATE03', AgentId=null, BuildId=null, AgentOwnAddress='192.168.70.229', AlternativeAddresses=[127.0.0.1], Port=9090, Version='29879', PluginsVersion='NA', AvailableRunners=[], AvailableVcs=[], AuthorizationToken='', PingCode='MKH4lrA7rQn3nZFQUxaMPsorTqpjzoh6'}
[2014-02-19 10:37:20,239]   INFO - agent.impl.AgentPortFileWriter - Writing agent runtime file to C:\BuildAgent\logs\buildAgent.port
[2014-02-19 10:37:20,239]   INFO - agent.impl.AgentPortFileWriter - Launcher version is 29879
[2014-02-19 10:37:20,239]   INFO - agent.impl.AgentPortFileWriter - Writing agent runtime file to C:\BuildAgent\logs\buildAgent.port :DONE!
[2014-02-19 10:37:20,239]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Build agent started
[2014-02-19 10:37:20,299]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Call http://buserver.ff.local/RPC2 buildServer.registerAgent3: java.net.UnknownHostException: buserver.ff.local
[2014-02-19 10:37:20,299]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Connection to TeamCity server is probably lost. Will be trying to restore it. Take a look at logs/teamcity-agent.log for details (unless you're using custom logging).
```

builtAgent.properties:

```
#Generated properties (see buildAgent.dist.properties for description)
#Tue Feb 18 16:41:59 CST 2014
name=DREPTATE03
ownAddress=192.168.70.229
ownPort=9090
serverUrl=http\://buserver.ff.local
workDir=C\:\\BuildAgent\\work
tempDir=C\:\\BuildAgent\\temp
#User defined properties
#Tue Feb 18 16:41:59 CST 2014
env.TEAMCITY_JRE=C\:\\BuildAgent\\jre
```

Any ideas why I cannot see the Agent in Unauthorized group on the server? I ran out of ideas....

Answer (score 0):

specify your Teamcity ip address in the /etc/hosts file. start you agent and now your agent will appear in disconnected agents list.